# Bootstrap - why is my div content merging on browser resize?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap for a site layout. I am using all `row-fluid` for the rows and all of my spans equal 12 when summed. But I am continuously having a problem with content "leaking" between divs and not stacking like in the fluid grid examples. I am including in the this in the `<HEAD>` as suggested.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

For example:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span8 offset1 categoryLabel" id="category"></div>
<div class="span1 sortby">ALPHABETIC</div>
<div class="span1 sortby">POPULARITY</div>
<div class="span1 sortby">DATE</div>
</div>                                              
<div class="row-fluid">
```

The layout is fine on a larger resolution. But once I shrink the browser size, the "Alphabetic, Popularity and Date" all bleed into each other so it looks like: "Alphularidate". They don't 'stack' as expected.

Comment: are they supposed to be displayed below each other or next to each other? if next to each other maybe they need a min-width so they dont overlap

Comment: Yes, they should stack as in the Bootstrap `fluid` demos on the Bootstap site.

Comment: this seems like tabular data to me... i would use a table for this. i still dont understand what you want. if the cells arent supposed to be next to each other on wide screen dont float them, use clear etc.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. i solve the problem by updating the bootstrap links

Comment: it actually does. for tabular data you should use actual tables.

Comment: what makes this "tabular data"? is there actually a technical difference between tabular and grid, or is it just semantical? i guess i'm confused as to where to use a grid vs a table. sorry if i misunderstood your explanation.

Comment: you need to use a table element. its far easier then forcing other elements to behave like a table. table = grid

Answer (score 0):

It's because the span1 columns aren't wide enough for your column headings. See this example where I've made the text smaller and coloured the columnshttp://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/QKZzZ/

```
body{
font-size:50%;
}
.span1, .span8{
background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: why does this receive a -1? The same thing actually occurred to me although the content seems to fit just fine as it's only 0.5em.

Comment: _why does this receive a -1?_ I guess someone decided to vote the answer down for some reason. As @BenjaminR correctly noted, in general you would wrap everything in a container div. I couldn't tell from the code you posted if you had done this or not. If you haven't already done so, then wrap your code in either a **container** or **container-fluid** div This doesn't solve anything though.The root cause of your problem is as I noted, the heading text is too wide for the span1 grids. You can see from my example that even at 50% some of the text is too wide to fit in the grid. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In your question at least, you have not defined a container div to wrap your rows.  The container div is a critical part of the bootstrap scaffolding, and if missing, will lead to all kinds of odd behaviour.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8 offset1 categoryLabel" id="category"></div>
    <div class="span1 sortby">ALPHABETIC</div>
    <div class="span1 sortby">POPULARITY</div>
    <div class="span1 sortby">DATE</div>
  </div><!-- end row -->
  <!-- more rows here -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

You can inspect or download this fluid Twitter Bootstrap example as a reference:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

Comment: Yes, everything is wrapped in a `<div class="container-fluid">`. Sorry for not specifying that but if I included the entire structure it would be quite a lot of code. I have lots of nested divs and rows altogether.

Answer (score -1):

Updated the bootstrap cdn links to 2.2 and it is working as it should now.